# English verbs processing ending with 'e'

Tags: python, nlp, stemming, text-processing

I am implementing few string replacers, with these conversions in mind

```
'thou sittest' → 'you sit'
'thou walkest' → 'you walk'
'thou liest' → 'you lie'
'thou risest' → 'you rise'
```

If I keep it naive it is possible to use regex for this case to find & replace, like `thou [a-z]+est`

But the trouble comes in English verbs that end with `e` because based on the context I need to trim the `est` in some & trim just `st` in the rest

What is the quick-dirty solution to achieve this?

Comment: Look into Word Stemming with NLTK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the most quick and dirty:

```
import nltk
words = set(nltk.corpus.words.words())
for old in 'sittest walkest liest risest'.split():
    new = old[:-2]
    while new and new not in words:
        new = new[:-1]
    print(old, new)
```

Output:

```
sittest sit
walkest walk
liest lie
risest rise
```

UPDATE. A slightly less quick and dirty (works e.g. for `rotest` → verb `rot`, not noun `rote`):

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
for old in 'sittest walkest liest risest rotest'.split():
    new = old[:-2]
    while new and not wn.synsets(new, pos='v'):
        new = new[:-1]
    print(old, new)
```

Output:

```
sittest sit
walkest walk
liest lie
risest rise
rotest rot
```

Comment: Note that it also correctly removes the double consonant from "sittest"!

Comment: That is _really_ quick and dirty... I like it.

Comment: Awesome so far, I was indeed hunting down if there is a method like word.is_verb(). This works the best. Accepting.

Comment: @Kirill Here is my work in https://github.com/nehemiahjacob/CKJV I am building a modernised bible translation based on KJV. You deserve kudos a lot.

Comment: @itsneo Thanks. Who knows, maybe I will use your project one day, as I'm doing a somewhat similar thing for word-to-word translation.